# Can One Run Selenium Tests on Debian Virtual Machine?

Tags: django, macos, selenium, debian, vagrant

I'm trying to wrap my head around this and figure out if it's possible.  I've been doing Django development on a Mac running OS X 10.10.  My production machine is a Debian server running on AWS.  Recently, I decide to move my development to a Debian virtual machine built with Vagrant that runs on my Mac because I'm tired of having to maintain two different runtime environments.  The problem is that I have a number of Selenium functional tests that I've been running on my Mac that I'd like to keep using.  Is it possible to install Firefox and Selenium on the Debian VM and run my tests on that box and see them running in the browser as I do now on my Mac?  Also, would it be possible to run them on my AWS production server?  It seems to me that these tests won't run once I start running things outside of my current OS X environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Works great for me, for years. Same, much better when running the same OS. I use Ubuntu on VMWare Fusion, running selenium on Chrome with Chrome driver (doesn't work with Chromium, works great with Chrome).

Just make sure you have the correct driver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: OK, but if you're running your tests on your Ubuntu VM, do you have to install a desktop environment (e.g. GNOME or KDE which I just read about) in order to see the Chrome browser opening and closing as the tests execute?  Sorry if this seems like a stupid question but I have zero experience with Linux desktop environments.

Comment: Download and  install the Ubuntu Desktop from Ubuntu website, then Chrome (browse to Google and click the link) , Selenium (with pip), and then download the correct web driver.

Comment: @Robert you do not necessarily need a desktop, I use centos (again a different OS but same idea) and run FireFox in headless mode, works great, I use Serenity on top of selenium and I get all screenshot from all steps of the script

Comment: @FrédéricHenri the question is about moving Selenium with the entire development environment, I think.

Comment: @AviahLaor, true, I focused at the AWS part, it would not be useful to full X env on those instances. locally, if host wants to move everything to Debian, right, a desktop would be better unless he's using CLI only (vi, emacs works great too) and "hand" testing can still be done on the host

Comment: Thanks for these responses.  It seems like I would need to install some type of X Windows server on my Mac (which I know nothing about) and have Cinnamon "talk" to it.  But I will look at @FrédéricHenri suggestion before going that route.  I'll let everyone know what I end up doing.